# setting custom Icon

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I am struggling with adding a custom icon to a `QToolButton`.
I have a resource file(properly under RESOURCES in the .pro file):
myResourceFile.qrc containing

```
/images
ICON_TEST.png
```

and code

```
dragButton = new QToolButton(this);
QString resourcePath = ":/images/ICON_TEST.png";
QPixmap pixIcon(resourcePath); //THE LINE THAT GIVES THE ERROR!
dragButton->setIcon(QIcon(pixIcon));
```

I get the error:

no match for call to QPixmap(QString &)

How do I pass the proper path to the QPixmap object and then the object to setIcon()?

edit:
Just confirmed that the .png file exists and is recognized by Qt:

```
File exists - true   ":/images/ICON_TEST.png"
```

with:

```
 qDebug()<<"File exists -"<<QFileInfo(":/images/ICON_TEST.png").exists()<<" "<<
              QFileInfo(":/images/ICON_TEST.png").absoluteFilePath();
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:** *below as answer*

Question remains, why this happened? The variable pixIcon is declared in the .h file of the class as:

```
QPixmap pixIcon;
```

and assigned a value in the constructor:

```
 pixIcon(resourcePath);
```

Which to me seems to be *almost* equivalent to doing it in one line.

This was on Windows Vista with Qt Creator 2.0.

Comment: QPixmap has a constructor with QString parameter, so are you sure you've included all the headers?

Comment: Just checked, and even added #include <QPixmap> to the .cpp file(eventhough it's already in the proper .h file) and I still get this error. And I checked the documentation, and it has the function overload that accepts QString & + 2 parameters with default values so passing QString SHOULD be sufficient IMO.

Comment: Please, give more code, especially, the line, that has error. And to test if QToolButton can change icon at all, try to do `dragButton->setIcon(QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirIcon).pixmap(128,128));` Icon should change to icon of a directory

Comment: What is your Qt version? Do you have all necessary packages installed? (If you're on Linux.)

Comment: Please post your solution in an answer to your question and accept it, otherwise the question is marked as non-answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when doing everything in one line it worked as it should have:

```
 dragButton->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(resourcePath)));
```